# How to include modules and submodules in the application directory?

Tags: python, python-2.7, paramiko

I am trying to deploy a small application on a server, which has some dependencies (specifically - paramiko). I do not have root access to the server, and creating a virtual environment is not possible. How can I somehow package the said dependencies along with my code? I looked through StackOverflow quite a bit getting answers using a single package, but paramiko has further dependencies like cryptography, which is where any given solution fails.

Of note is the fact that cryptography has nested modules. How do I include everything?

Comment: Sorry if this is a daft idea, but can't you just use `pip install --user`?

Comment: @PaulPanzer No, since the code won't run under my user profile. It will be copied to another machine before executing. Pip and other module install commands are not available to the user.